# Failed to connect to the database (Postgres) by Jmeter

Tags: database, postgresql, ssh, automation, jmeter

I'm trying to connect to the database (Postgres) using Jmeter, but I have the following problem:

**Response below**

```
Unable to create PoolableConnectionFactory (connection to local host: 5432 refused. Check that the host name and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP / IP connections.)
```

**Request below**

```
Database URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/auth?AutoReconnect=true
Username: XXXX
Password: XXXX
```

When I'm connected directly to Postgres, connected to the SSH tunnel. Is that it?

If so, how to proceed?
Do you have any settings?
Or on the machine?

Could someone help me and take a step by step?

Thank you very much in advance!

Estevão F. P. Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that your PostgreSQL instance is [started](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/server-start.html)
2. Make sure that your PostgreSQL instance is accepting incoming TCP/IP connections, you should have the following line in [*postgresql.conf* file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/config-setting.html):

   ```
   tcpip_socket = true
   ```
3. It might be the case you need to whitelist your IP address so PostgreSQL could accept incoming connections from it, it can be done in the [*pg_hba.conf* file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)
4. Prior to trying to connect to your database using JMeter make sure that you can successfully connect using [*psql* command-line utility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html)
5. Double check your JDBC Connection configuration as the error message you posted looks suspicious, especially these whitespaces:

   ```
   local host: 5432
        ^     ^
   ```

   because `localhost` and `local host` are different [DNS Hostnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) from the Postgres JDBC driver point of view.

Just in case check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) to learn more about the specifics of the database load testing using JMeter.